# Will using the following logic work on solving the integral $A$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integral

$$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \cos(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{x}{2}\right)=A $$

This integral can be solved directly with integration techniques however, for the sake of the question please assume i am not able to do so (find an anti-derivative).

I will reflect the function on the Y axis such that

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \cos(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{x}{2}\right) = \int_{\frac{-\pi}{3}}^{0} \cos(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

I, then subtract both integrals over the same limits of integration to obtain an antiderivative $P(x)$ and a value $K$

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \cos(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{x}{2}\right) - \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\cos(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{x}{2}\right) = P(x)|_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}=K$$

Since the functions are reflections of each other I can say that the above is equivalent to

$$-\int_{\frac{-\pi}{3}}^0 \cos(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{x}{2}\right) + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \cos(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{x}{2}\right) = P(x)|_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}=K$$

So based on this, can I use $P(x)$ to find the value of Integral $A$?
[image]

Kind Regards,

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: The second to last line and the last are not equal. You have that
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \cos(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{x}{2}\right) - \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\cos(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{x}{2}\right) = \\
-\left[\int_{\frac{-\pi}{3}}^0 \cos(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{x}{2}\right) - \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \cos(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]$$

Comment: Thank you , edited.

Comment: Well I don't see what will make it better. You just get that
$$
P(x)|_0^{\pi/3}=A-\int_{-\pi/3}^0 \cos(x)\tan\left( \frac{\pi}{x} - \frac{x}{2} \right)
$$

Comment: @bjorn93. I do not see why your answer has been downvoted. It is the solution to the problem.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - probably because the question was not "how can I find an anti-derivative and solve this problem" (the OP said they know how to do that), but rather "does this particular technique also work to solve the problem", which bjorn93's post did not address.

Comment: Norse is correct. Assuming that this even allows you to find an antiderivative $P(x)$ for the modified integral, all you've accomplished is to change the interval of integration for your original integral. If you couldn't figure out the original interval, it is unlikely the new interval will be any better.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The reason i asked this question is that i am studying an integral that has no elementary anti-derivative and i noticed that doing the above technique yielded a function after integration. Furthermore i noticed that the above technique works SOMETIMES for some integrals as $A=-1/2*P(Lower Limit)+ f(Upper Limit) $ where f(x) is the function being integrated, and as such i wanted to see if anything like this has been used before or anything of the sorts

Comment: I don't understand the question. If your antiderivative is an "elementary" function the question is solved. Don't you know the fundamental theorem of analysis? if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f$ has got an antiderivative $F$ and $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$. The problem is such antiderivative is not always an "elementary" function. Thus, when it's not an "elementary" function it's useless to obtain a closed-form for $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)dx$